# MVC4 Jquery validate checkbox to check at least one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, requiredfieldvalidator

i'm implementing a checkbox question for let user to choose. However, if admin set the question mandatory to true, the checkbox must select at least 1 to submit, else a message will prompt user to select. Tried the jquery but when click button, nothing happen.

Any mistakes that ive done?

My View:

```
    @model List<IFXSurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>

    <script>

            var messageContainer = $('.errormessage');

            $('#save').click(function () {
                // Get all mandatory containers
                var mandatory = $('.mandatory');
                $.each(mandatory, function () {
                    var numChecked = $(this).find('input:checked').length;
                    if (numChecked === 0) {
                        messageContainer.text('At least one checkbox must be selected.');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

            $('.mandatory').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
                messageContainer.text('');
            });


    </script>

    <br />
    <h2>Questions</h2>
    <br />

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="errormessage"></div>
           <div class="checkboxcontainer mandatory">
              @for (int x = 0; x < Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion.Count(); x++)
                  {


                           <input type="checkbox" name="[@i].MultiAnswer[@x]" value="@Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion[x]" />
                           @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].MultiAnswer[x])
                           @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].MultiAnswer[x], Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion[x].ToString(), new { @class = "questionlist1" })



         }
  </div>

    <button type="button" id="save">Save</button> 
}
```

After generating the checkbox in HTML:

```
<div class="checkboxcontainer mandatory">
<input type="checkbox" name="[0].MultiAnswer[0]" value="1">
<input name="[0].MultiAnswer[0]" type="hidden" value="">
<label class="questionlist1" for="">1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="[0].MultiAnswer[1]" value="2">
<input name="[0].MultiAnswer[1]" type="hidden" value="">
<label class="questionlist1" for="">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="[0].MultiAnswer[2]" value="3">
<input name="[0].MultiAnswer[2]" type="hidden" value="">
<label class="questionlist1" for="">3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing built in to MVC that will do this validation for you. You will need to use jquery/javascript to check if any are checked (and you will also need to check again on the server (which you could do by writing your own validation attribute)

Comment: First your view does not make sense and should not even bind correctly when you post. You have a checkbox with indexed names and unchecked checkboxes do not post back so if any are unchecked, you have non-consecutive indexers which means binding will fail. Then you give the `value` attribute of the checkbox `@Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion[x]` which assuming its not a `bool` and `@Model[i].MultiAnswer[x]` is, binding would also fail. You need to show your models and the outer `for` loop in the view to understand better what your trying to do.

Comment: As for the script, I suggest wrapping the group of checkboxes inside a div and then `if (Model[i].Mandatory == true)`, give the div a class name (say) `<div class="mandatory">`. Then you can handle the `.submit()` event, get all elements with that class name, and use a `$.each()` function to test of any of its checkboxes are checked. If not, then cancel the submit and display an error.

Comment: Need a break for a while, but if you can't solve it then I can add an example in a few hours.

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npjyu58e/) for an example of what you could do. Leave all checkboxes unchecked and click 'save' - a message is shown. Then check one in group 2 and save again. Finally check one in group 4 and click save again

Comment: A few possible issues. First you have given all the containers the class name `mandatory` and then only generated the controls if `Model[i].Mandatory` is `true` so not sure if that's what you really want. Next, your button is a submit button so the form is submitting (you have not cancelled it) - to test this, temporarily comment out `<input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="save" />` and add `<button type=button id="save">Save</button>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke , i had removed the Model[i].Mandatory == true, and change the button to <button type=button id="save">Save</button>, but still nothing happen when click. Really have no idea whats going wrong?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i have put the output of checkbox generating in HTML.

Comment: If this is verbatim how your view is laid out, you're attempting to bind events to markup that hasn't been rendered yet. Either move the script after the markup, or wrap it all in a ready handler.

Comment: @Edward.K, In addition to my answer, the html you have shown indicates that this will not bind to your model correctly on post back.

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks, useful info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your giving all the containing `<div>` elements `class="mandatory"` and only ever generating checkboxes if `Model[i].Mandatory` is `true` so you html should be

```
for (int x = 0; x < Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion.Count; x++)
{
  @{var attributes = Model[i].Mandatory ? "checkboxgroup mandatory" : "checkboxgroup";}
  <div class="@attributes">
    <div class="message></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="[@i].MultiAnswer[@x]" value="@Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion[x]" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].MultiAnswer[x])
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].MultiAnswer[x], Model[i].Choice_SubQuestion[x].ToString(), new { @class = "questionlist1" })
  </div>
}
<input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="save" />
```

Next, your button is a submit button so the form is actually submitting (before the error message has a chance to become visible). Change the scripts to

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  var canSubmit = true;
  // Get all mandatory containers
  var mandatory = $('.mandatory');
  $.each(mandatory, function() {
    var numChecked = $(this).find('input:checked').length;
    if (numChecked === 0) {
      canSubmit = false; // signal we can't submit
      // display error message;
      $(this).children('.message').text('At least one checkbox must be selected');

      return false; // exit the loop
    }
  });
  if (!canSubmit) {
    return false; // cancel the default submit
  }
});

$('.mandatory').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  $(this).closest('.mandatory').children('.message').text(''); // clear any existing error message
});
```

Note also the scripts must be at the bottom of the page (immediately before the closing `</body>` tag) or wrapped in `$(document).ready() { ..... }` or `$(function() { ..... });` (shorthand version).

Comment: Side note - look at the checkbox you generating - it does not have an `id` attribute and the label does not have a `for` attribute pointing to the checkbox (too long to explain why this happens in your case), but either wrap the checkbox inside the label, or manually add unique `id` attributes to each checkbox and the `for` attribute in the checkbox label.

Comment: Oops - missed the closing `}` - see edit to answer - it should output `<div class="checkboxgroup mandatory">` or `<div class="checkboxgroup">` depending on the value of `Model[i].Mandatory`

Comment: See update for alternative (may or may not need to wrap the `var attributes = ...` inside `@{ ... }` depending on other code in your view)

Comment: i tried but when i press the submit, it will straight go to controller..looks like it did not detect the jquery. Either i tried for wrap the var attributes inside @{...} or not is same. Any idea? THanks.

Comment: Of course it works. You must have other things wrong in your code. I'll create a DotNetFiddle for you a bit later to prove it

Comment: hi @stephen muecke, sorry for mistakes. It works now!

Comment: Bugger, didn't see your message and went ahead and created this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBtua7) for you anyway :). But might be useful anyway - it shows one technique for adding the `id` attributes and making the labels work. It also shows how you **should** be using a view model with a (say) `bool IsSelected` property and binding to it using `CheckBoxFor()` so that you model will be correctly bound when you post back